# Should I have to batch all the time for sql for web programming written in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm wondering if should I have to batch sql multiple insert, update, delete for a just simple web program.. I'm a junior web javascript full stack developer(1y) and never heard of 'batch sql', but my senior who is a c++ programmer, doesn't know js at all just told me that I have to do batch for multiple sql..

I've followed mysql guide for multiple sql queries like '
insert into dbTable(columns) values([values])' <-this works, I just wrote it simply since I think anyone who reads it can understand the multiple insert query that mysql supports.

Anyway, he just read my code and keep telling me where is 'batch' code for multiple rows and I quite don't get what he meant as I understood that that query works now without any issues. and since I've read a bit about what batch is that basically it's about dealing with multiple queries, right?

I just.. don't understand what he's trying to say. It's just keep telling me without any additional orders or explanations. 'add batch code' <- this is it.

???

Should I have to add batch code even for the code supporting multiple inserts?

Please help... I'm very confusing.

Comment: By "batch" do you mean "multi-insert"? If you're inserting N of something, using a mutli-insert can make things a lot more efficient. MySQL's version of this isn't hard to use.

Comment: Are you using Node.js or something else?

Comment: @tadman yep, that's how I understood from my senior. He didn't say that much about 'why and how' to do. just 'add batch code'. this is it when I even ask back him 'why?, mysql supports multiple inserts and my code works'... several times.

Comment: @tadman back - node and front - vue

Comment: For the back-end, consider [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) or an ORM like that, which can handle a lot of this "batching" for you automatically with features like [`bulkCreate()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate).

Comment: @tadman Got it, thanks! one more additional question! User won't insert data that much. maybe upto 10 rows? I guess, as they can only insert the data to the specific location's traffic data for a specific calculation result purpose only. Any city doesn't have that specific traffic data that much in korea... I've understood bulkCreate is more for insert 'bulk' data at once for efficiency and Sequelize. I've asked my senior about the purpose of doing batch and he said for 'support multiple insert not for the sequelization' which caused confusing.....

Comment: @tadman So.. are there much difference in tems of performing for only upto 10 rows between using bulkCreate and not using it?

Comment: The statement processing round-trip and transaction overhead is the big cost factor here. In practice adding 1 row is about as quick as adding N (N < ~50) so it makes sense to mass-insert to avoid the dreaded "N queries" problem. If you can call a function like `bulkCreate()` and commit all of your records in one shot it's usually way more efficient.